# stack overflow error?

Tags: java

I was working on an accounts application. when I tried to run the invoice form something called stack overflow exception occurred...tell me what to do about it.. everything was fine I suppose before I declared an invoice object in Stock class.
this was output...

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:215)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:394)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:433)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:158)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:10)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)

    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
    at Stock.<init>(Stock.java:670)
    at Invoice.<init>(Invoice.java:1135)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Comment: Well, no-one can help you without seeing the corresponding code!

Comment: You probably have a recursive call that does not terminate, but I can't see the problem since I don't have your source code.  Post a code example (http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: This one looks simple. Stock and Invoice constructors are called in a recursive manner.

Comment: in Invoice c-tor you call new Stock(), and that new Stock() c-tor, you have new Invoice(). There you have it, w/o the code :)

Comment: @Oli, you dont need the code, it's obvious.

Comment: @Vivek Maskara you're stuck with recursion

Comment: Well, at least you're in the right *place*...

Comment: @bestsss: Of course.  But we can't offer any sensible advice as to how to fix the issue without seeing the code.

Comment: @Oli, to offer any advice you'd need the logic and relation between the classes. Having cross calls in the constructors, though, it's a rookie mistake and needs to be sorted out by removing the call to the owning (strong) class c-tor. And passing this as reference instead.

Answer (score 17):

In the `Invoice` constructor, you're creating a new `Stock` object (in line 1135).

In the `Stock` constructor, you're creating a new `Invoice` object (in line 670).

In the `Invoice` constructor, you're creating a new `Stock` object (in line 1135).

and so on and on, until you reach the maximum stack depth. You need to figure out which one of `Invoice` and `Stock` should automatically create new instances of the other, or create the objects and then assign them to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Well.. We need to see some code before we can answer you, but stackoverflow exceptions usually happens when you have some code calling itself without ever ending (Recursion, without progress). So you should look at your code, and find out under what conditions it should terminate the loop, and why it doesnt do that yet :)